# SELECTS: Hide the selected option on a secondary select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select with the same elements (options) in it.
What I am trying to do is that when the user select a value from the first select box, the second select box hides that option, and automatically select the first visible option if the selected option was the same as the one in the first select.

I know that `:first` selects the first element of a group of "objects", and that `:visible` only select the "visible" ones, so i was thinking that using `:first` of `:visible` should work, but what I am getting is no selection at all.

if I remove the `:visible` it works unless the second select box has the first element selected, and the user selects the first element on the first select box

This is what I have so far, please keep in mind that I have tried `:first` and `:visible` in any combination, but I really think that the problem here is that "hide hasn't finished its job when I use `:visible`

```
$('#style_position').change(function(){
    var sel_pos_id      = $(this).val();
    var sel_xtr_pos_id  = $('#style_position_extra').val();
    $('#style_position_extra option[value=' + sel_pos_id + ']').hide().siblings().show();
    if(sel_pos_id==sel_xtr_pos_id){
        $('#style_position_extra option')
            .removeAttr('selected')
            .filter(':visible')   //I also tried find(':visible')
            .filter(':first')     //I also tried find(':first')
                .attr('selected','selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: don't use hide() on options IE doesn't support it, question now becomes will you need to get the options back if they are removed

Comment: Remove the item from the list. Hiding it will not work.

Comment: I answered a similar question a while back, it has slightly different requirements to your's but maybe it'll help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834461

Comment: Yes, I need it back.  So if hide doesn't work on options, my next solution is to create an Array and re-populate the select (or remove and then add what is missing to not cause any weird refresh effect ?)

Comment: methods below would be imperceptible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method

```
/* cache a set of options from second select*/
var $opts=$('#style_position_extra option').clone();

$('#style_position').change(function(){
    var sel_pos_id      = $(this).val();
    /* find matching option copy*/
    var $newOpts=$opts.filter(function(){
            return this.value !=sel_pos_id;                                             
    }).clone();
    /* replace exisiting options with match*/
    $('#style_position_extra').html( $newOpts);
});
```

Here's another possibly simpler one

```
$('#style_position').change(function(){
    var selected=$(this).find('option').not(':selected').clone();
    $('#style_position_extra').html(selected);
});
```

Comment: a few small changes: `'#style_position_extra options` should be `'#style_position_extra option` `and this.value==sel_pos_id;` should be `this.value!=sel_pos_id;` . I have to test it on other browsers to see if it keeps the selected element, but it seems working  on chrome

Comment: OK..I had concept backwards and I have a bad habit of pluralizing "option"

Comment: VERY close, I need to re-select the one the was selected initially. I figured out the code but I am going to accept your answer as I got there thanks to you

Comment: post some html next time in a fiddle, will save effort and small errors

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `charlietfl` I figured out, here is the final answer:

```
$('#style_position').change(function(){
    var sel_pos_id      = $(this).val();
    var sel_xtr_pos_id  = $('#style_position_extra').val();

    var selected=$(this).find('option').not(':selected').clone();
    $('#style_position_extra').html(selected)
    if(sel_pos_id!=sel_xtr_pos_id){
        $('#style_position_extra option[value=' + sel_xtr_pos_id + ']').attr('selected','selected');
    }
});
```

This code will automatically select a different option if the two selects have the same option, or it will keep the same option selected in the second selectbox